# Visual Studio Install Stopped Working

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation, crash

I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate on my Sony VAIO running a 64-bit Windows 8.
I tried using ISO's and Web Installers but everytime I try to run the .exe file it shows me the Visual Studio intro screen but then it APPCRASHes.

Online I found some solutions regarding registry edits but those didn't help me.

This is my Error Log:

```
Logboeknaam:   Application
Bron:          Application Error
Datum:         24/09/2013 18:31:53
Gebeurtenis-id:1000
Taakcategorie: (100)
Niveau:        Fout
Trefwoorden:   Klassiek
Gebruiker:     n.v.t.
Computer:      VAIO_nicolas
Beschrijving:
Naam van toepassing met fout: en_visual_studio_ultimate_2012_x86_web_installer_920948.exe, versie: 11.0.50727.1, tijdstempel: 0x4fd9f28c
Naam van module met fout: unknown, versie: 0.0.0.0, tijdstempel: 0x00000000
Uitzonderingscode: 0xc0000005
Foutmarge: 0x0db20077
Id van proces met fout: 0x%9
Starttijd van toepassing met fout: 0x%10
Pad naar toepassing met fout: %11
Pad naar module met fout: %12
Rapport-id: %13
Volledige pakketnaam met fout: %14
Relatieve toepassings-id van pakket met fout: %15
Gebeurtenis-XML:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-09-24T16:31:53.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>27459</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>VAIO_nicolas</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>en_visual_studio_ultimate_2012_x86_web_installer_920948.exe</Data>
    <Data>11.0.50727.1</Data>
    <Data>4fd9f28c</Data>
    <Data>unknown</Data>
    <Data>0.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>00000000</Data>
    <Data>c0000005</Data>
    <Data>0db20077</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

My System is fully updated, I have no idea what I should do next.

Does anyone have experience with this one?

Thanks in advance!

Nicolas

Comment: this may cause .net framework isn't installed :D

Comment: try this: http://superuser.com/questions/791745/i-cannot-install-any-version-of-visual-studio-in-windows-8-1

Answer (score 1):

I went into Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Windows Features

```
disabled .NET 3.5
```

And it worked..